# Get Date object from dll using JNA

Tags: date, dll, jna

I am trying to get logs using the method in .dll. I could not find Date mapping in JNA. 
The dll method shown below:

```
long GetGeneralLogData(long* apnEnrolslNumber, long* apnVerifyMode,long* apnInOutMode,DATE* apnDateTime) 

//Implementation in C# and it works fine.
public static extern int FK_GetGeneralLogData_StringID_Workcode(int anHandleIndex, ref string apnEnrollNumber, ref int apnVerifyMode, ref int apnInOutMode, ref DateTime apnDateTime, ref int apnWorkCode);
```

I could not get the Date object in Jna.

Comment: Hi Abdy, welcome to StackOverflow.  You have not given us enough information to help answer your question.  What is the type of `DATE` in the dll you are using?  Is it a `struct`?  I think using a `byte[]` mapping is probably wrong because the function will return a pointer to the date, so your byte array is giving you only the pointer value.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, Daniel.  I have only a method header. It receives DATE* object. Also, I have a C# implementation of the method. In C# it sends  (ref DateTime apnDateTime) object and it works well. But I could not get the Date objet in Java using Jna.

Comment: Well I can't give a definitive answer, but based on the C# `DateTime` you probably want to use a `LongByReference` which will point to the 64-bit representation (which you'll have to further parse using the 62-bit tick value).  But JNA does C, not C# so there's no guarantee that the `DATE` type in your API has the same 64-bit interpretation.   In sum, if they want you to use a type in a function they should define that type, otherwise in either C or Java you (and the compiler) have no idea what to do with that variable.